# Dose Flutter or Dart have any method equivalent to hasProperty() method in JS or isset method in PH

Tags: dart, flutter

Dose Flutter or Dart have any method equivalent to hasProperty() method in JS or isset method in PHP. for example: x.hasOwnProperty('y')

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection, you could make one.
The thing is, `dart:mirror` is disabled in Flutter. So no.

The recommended solution is instead to use code-generators using [source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen)

You can take a look at [reflectable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/reflectable), a code-generation library that mimics reflection.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, there isn't an exact equivalent to

JavaScript's hasOwnProperty or PHP's isset method, but you can

achieve similar functionality using different approaches.

- For Checking Variable Existence:

Dart doesn't have an equivalent to PHP's isset for variables. However, Dart

variables are nullable by default, so you can use the null-aware operators

for this purpose:

String? myVariable; // Nullable variable

if (myVariable != null) {

// Variable is not null

}