# Flutter: How to check if Widget is a scrolling widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Widgets like `ListView`, `GridView`, `SingleChildScrollView` etc are scrollable widgets while `Container`, `SizedBox`, `Column` are not.

Is there any way to check if the `Widget` is scrollable, using something like

```
Widget widget = SomeWidget();
bool scrollable = widget.isScrollable(): // any property like this?
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write something like this:

```
Widget widget = SomeWidget();
```

then you are basically [Downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting) your widget to `Widget` class, which is the parent of all classes. If you check the [Widget class in doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Widget-class.html) you should see only 3 methods exposed. Which are:

1. `createElement`
2. `debugFillProperties`
3. `toStringShort`

> bool scrollable = widget.isScrollable(): // any property like this?

So no, this is not possible.

**However**, you know that the widget has to be a subclass of [ScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView-class.html) or is of type [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) so you can write a utility method for yourself. Like

```
bool isScrollable(Widget widget) => widget is ScrollView || widget is SingleChildScrollView;
```

Comment: Thanks, I already knew `ListView`, `GridView` extends `ScrollView` and `SingleChildScrollView` itself is a `StatelessWidget`, these are some common widgets, what if the library that I am creating is passed another widget say `AbcWidget` which also extends `StatelessWidget` like `SingleChildScrollView`, how will I be able to figure it out then?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to detect it the way you're saying. there is no common interface for **ALL** scrollables to detect such. But from a software design perspective if I was building a custom scrolling view then I would definitely extend from `ScrollView` instead of building it ground up.

Comment: Could you use reflection and check whether the widget contains any member of type  `ScrollController`?

Comment: Flutter disables dart reflection package `dart:mirror`. [Details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53133499/5223309). You can do code generation though but I don't know how it will help.