# How to check if a widget is Scrollable?

Tags: flutter, widget, scrollable

I need to distinguish a widget between scrollable and non-scrollable. As a developers, we know that widgets like ListView, SingleChildScrollView, GridView, Sliver,and so on are scrollable and others like Container, Column and etc. are non-scrollable. But how can we differ them programmatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: How to check if Widget is a scrolling widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007700/flutter-how-to-check-if-widget-is-a-scrolling-widget)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007700/flutter-how-to-check-if-widget-is-a-scrolling-widget) answer check if the widget is a ScrollView or a SingleChildScrollView

```
bool isScrollable(Widget widget) => widget is ScrollView || widget is SingleChildScrollView;
```

Comment: When a question is a near identical question to another the correct way to answer is to mark this question as duplicate, linking to the other question